# How do you define non-inline properties in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

In C++/CLI, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235304.aspx), you can define properties as such:

```
public ref class Vector sealed { 
public:
   property double x {
      double get() {
         return _x;
      }

      void set( double newx ) {
         _x = newx;
      }
   } // Note: no semi-colon
};
```

However, if you simply prototype the the property like this:

```
public ref class Vector sealed { 
public:
   property double x {
      double get() ;
      void set( double newx );
   } // Note: no semi-colon
};
```

How would you go about creating the implementation for those prototypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to implement the given property x, what you need are the following 2 functions:

```
double Vector::x::get() {
    return _x;
}

void Vector::x::set(double newx) {
    _x = newx;
}
```